# Extract all occurrence of string from a array of strings before "-" in perl script

Tags: perl

I need to extract all strings before -*,
e.g. 100002098 and 0004184022 and 66680 and 1247764 and 843804 and append into a url "www.xyz.com/mystring"

for that i have written below perl code but i am missing something in regular expression, can anybody help me in this

```
my @str = ("100002098-2","0004184022-2","66680-2","1247764-2", "843804-0");  
foreach my $arr(@str){  
    if($arr =~ s/-.*//sr){  
        #url = append(url+$arr);
        print $arr. "\n";  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the `append` function?

Answer (score 7):

You're close.

You don't need `sr` as regex modifiers. I had to go look what `r` did:

> r  - perform non-destructive substitution and return the new value

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Which will - in this case - mean your 'if' statement is testing the result of the regular expression, but you're NOT actually changing your `$arr`.*

`s` looks irrelevant too, but isn't what's causing your problem:

> s
>   Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

So this should work:

```
my @str = ("100002098-2","0004184022-2","66680-2","1247764-2", "843804-0");  
foreach my $arr(@str){  
    if($arr =~ s/-.*//){  
        print $arr. "\n";  
    }  
}
```

Also - appending in perl is done with `.`.

E.g. `print $url.$arr` or just stringifying: `print "$url/$arr\n";`

* for the sake of interest, you can make this work with `r` modifier on your regex:

```
my @str = ("100002098-2","0004184022-2","66680-2","1247764-2", "843804-0");  
foreach my $arr(@str){  
    if(my $new_arr = $arr =~ s/-.*//sr){  
        print $new_arr. "\n";  
    }  
}
```

But I'd suggest that's redundant, unless you particularly want to keep the old value of `$arr`.

Comment: don't take away /s; if there is a newline after the -, it will certainly be wanted.  and your suggestion with /r works differently than your one without /r if - is the first character.

Comment: Fair points. I was focussing on the source data provided, but some test cases for things of different formats would be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, this solution regex is good for any script, not only perl.

Comment: and for excecution of url on browser, i used as below:

$urluncomplete = 'http://www.example.com/' ;  
my $url = ($urluncomplete.$arr);  
   open_browser($url);

Answer (score 1):

I would use split to separate each element into an array, containing characters before the `-` in `$split[0]` and characters after in `$split[1]`. 
You can then print these out. I've included an if statement after the print to only print the numbers if both `$split[0]` and `$split[1]` exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @str = qw(100002098-2 0004184022-2 66680-2 1247764-2 843804-0 1234 -5678);  
foreach (@str){
    my @split = split(/-/);
    print "$split[0]\n" if $split[0] and $split[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, split works in perl script, and for other script regex is good option,

Answer (score 0):

Just because there is always more than one way to do it. If you don't want to change the $arr. This code ...

```
my @str = ("100002098-2","0004184022-2","66680-2","1247764-2", "843804-0");  
foreach my $arr(@str){  
    if($arr =~ m/(.*)-.*/){  
        print "untouched: ". $arr. "\n";  
        print "extracted: " .$1. "\n";  
    }  
}
```

... gives you ...

```
untouched: 100002098-2
extracted: 100002098
untouched: 0004184022-2
extracted: 0004184022
untouched: 66680-2
extracted: 66680
untouched: 1247764-2
extracted: 1247764
untouched: 843804-0
extracted: 843804
```